# Find all Polynomials $P$ such that $S(P(n)) = P(S(n))$.

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, proof-explanation

Find all Polynomials $P$ such that $S(P(n)) = P(S(n))$. Where $S(n)$ denotes the sum of the digits of $n$.

Here is my solution to this problem. We are asked to find all Polynomials that satisfies $S(P(n)) = P(S(n)) . . (*)$
Claim: we have equality in (*) if  and only if 
$P(x) = 0$, or $P(x) = x$.

Proof. Consider the linear polynomial, $P(x) = ax + b$ where $a, b$ are positive integers $\gt 0$ then we from $(*)$

$S(ax + b) = P(S(ax + b)) = a(S(ax + b)) + b . .(**)$

Since $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be $\gt 0$ then it follows that we cannot have equality in $(**)$

Similar, for any polynomial $P$, defined by
$P(x) = a_nx^{n - 1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + a_0$

$S(a_nx^{n - 1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + a_0) \ne P(S(a_nx^{n - 1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + a_0))$

Please, Is my proof correct?

Comment: Well, the constant $P(x)=1$ works, as does any single digit.

Comment: @lulu Please is my proof correct.

Comment: As the claim is false, the proof can not be correct.

Comment: @lulu so if I adjust the conditions then would that validate my proof?

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing because polynomials themselves don't have digits. Do you mean that the polynomial evaluated at natural number of values has this property? Or are you talking about the coefficients of the polynomial?

Comment: I don't understand your proof, even in the linear case.  As i say, as it stands the statement of the Claim is not correct, so there has to be an error in the proof somewhere.

Comment: @Michael McGovern My working is based on this, suppose $P(x) = 5x$ is the polynomial, then $S(P(2)) = S(10) = 1$

Comment: @lulu Please read the proof again, I was just plugging in values into $(*)$

Comment: So you are considering polynomials over the natural numbers evaluated at some point in their domain, right?

Comment: Yes @Michael McGovern

Comment: So is your claim that there exists a polynomial and a natural number at which the polynomial satisfies the conditions that you have stated above?

Comment: Yes @Michael McGovern, I know that(by inspection) that $P(x) = x$ and $P(x) = 0) are indeed solutions, so I tried to prove that it would be false for higher polynomials, I first considered a linear polynomial.

Comment: If your statement about the polynomial and your statement about the natural numbern are both only existentially quantified then you have proven it by finding a single example. If however you want to universally quantify one of the statements about either the polynomial or the natural number you need a more general proof. Universal quantification of the statement about the polynomial or the statement about the natural number also means you need to figure out which combination of universal and existential quantifiers can be disproven purely by counterexample.

Comment: Please include more detail.  For example, you never say what sort of polynomial $P(n)$ is.  Integer coefficients?  Rational?  Keep in mind that there are polynomials like $\frac {n(n+1)}2$ that take on integer values at integers but which do not have integer coefficients.

Comment: @lulu, integer coefficients.